# how to set custom permission to custom menu access?

Tags: users

I  am trying to create student management system in which i have been created custom 'registration form', for registering to website then i have created 'list of registered students' menu to show registered students.I want to set permissions such that admin can edit registration form and authenticated user can only see 'registration form',admin can see list of registered students but authenticated user can not see that list.So please guide me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this using a custom module, you can use hook_permission to defile your permissions, and use in the views. You can also restrict access by role and set the visibility if you use blocks fir the 'list of registered students'.

Comment: ok thank you i am done with this settings and its working

Comment: can u please tell mi how to add edit link in this to upadate self info

Comment: From views, Create a 'User' view, then add 'Link to edit User' field. Or by custom module something like **/user/{uid}/edit**. Also check this : https://drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/56/get-current-user-drupal-8